# How do you update multiple fields from another table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

This is the query I'm trying to accomplish:

```
update amdashboard
set (ASCID, ASCFirst, ASCLast, ASCOtherName, ASCAdd1, ASCAdd2,
     ASCCity, ASCState, ASCZip, ASCZip4, ASCY2007, ASCY2008, ASCY2009,
     ASCY2010, ASCY2011, ASCY2012, ASCEthnicity, ASCGender, ASCMaritalStatus)
= (select id, firstname, lastname, listingspousename, add1, add2,
          city, state, zip, zip4, y2007, y2008, y2009,
          y2010, y2011, y2012, Ethnicity, Gender, MaritialStatus
     from ASCNCOAClean
          inner join amdashboard
          on ASCNCOAClean.firstname = amdashboard.actorsfirst
          and ascncoaclean.lastname = amdashboard.actorslast)
    where exists (select id, firstname, lastname, listingspousename,
                         add1, add2, city, state, zip, zip4, y2007, y2008,
                         y2009, y2010, y2011, y2012, Ethnicity, Gender,
                         MaritialStatus
                    from ASCNCOAClean
                         inner join amdashboard
                         on ASCNCOAClean.firstname = amdashboard.actorsfirst
                         and ascncoaclean.lastname = amdashboard.actorslast);
```

I can't get this to work...receiving a syntax error on the first parenthesis. So, I figured I'd try on just one field. I tried this:

```
update amdashboard
set ascid = (select ascncoaclean.id
         from ASCNCOAClean 
         where ASCNCOAClean.firstname = amdashboard.actorsfirst
                           and ascncoaclean.lastname = amdashboard.actorslast)
where exists (select ascncoaclean.id
         from ASCNCOAClean 
         where ASCNCOAClean.firstname = amdashboard.actorsfirst
                           and ascncoaclean.lastname = amdashboard.actorslast);
```

This however returns and error 1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row. That seems silly. I know it's going to return more than one row...I want it to because I need to update multiple rows.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post some sample data or schema structure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The query you want would look something like this:

```
UPDATE amdashboard a, ASCNCOAClean b SET
   a.ASCID            = b.id,
   a.ASCFirst         = b.firstname,
   a.ASCLast          = b.lastname,
   a.ASCOtherName     = b.listingspousename,
   ...
   a.ASCMaritalStatus = b.MaritialStatus
WHERE a.actorsfirst = b.firstname;
```

Observe you will have to replace `...` with the rest of the column associations I didn't write.

But be careful with that, something tells me this query is going to do something very wrong to your database, because you are not relating the tables using a unique key. If there are two records with the same `ASCNCOAClean.firstname` you certainly will have loss of data.

Also observe that it is going to update **existing** records on `amdashboard`, not add new ones. If your intention is to migrate data from `ASCNCOAClean` to `amdashboard`, assuming `amdashboard` is a brand new, empty table, then the query you want is this:

```
INSERT INTO amdashboard (
    ASCID, ASCFirst, ASCLast, ASCOtherName, ASCAdd1, ASCAdd2, ASCCity, ASCState, 
    ASCZip, ASCZip4, ASCY2007, ASCY2008, ASCY2009, ASCY2010, ASCY2011, ASCY2012,
    ASCEthnicity, ASCGender, ASCMaritalStatus
)
SELECT
    id, firstname, lastname, listingspousename, add1, add2, city, state,
    zip, zip4, y2007, y2008, y2009, y2010, y2011, y2012, Ethnicity, Gender,
    MaritialStatus
FROM ASCNCOAClean;
```

Comment: Thanks...I had come to basically that solution.

Comment: update amdashboard inner join ASCNCOAClean 
    on ASCNCOAClean.firstname = amdashboard.actorsfirst and ascncoaclean.lastname = amdashboard.actorslast
set /*amdashboard.ascid = ascncoaclean.id,*/
 /*amdashboard.ascfirst = ascncoaclean.firstname,*/
 amdashboard.asclast = ascncoaclean.lastname,
 amdashboard.ascothername = ascncoaclean.listingspousename,
 amdashboard.ascadd1 = ascncoaclean.add1,
 amdashboard.ascadd2 = ascncoaclean.add2,
 amdashboard.asccity = ascncoaclean.city,
 amdashboard.ascstate = ascncoaclean.state,
 amdashboard.asczip = ascncoaclean.zip ... ;

Comment: Sorry, I'm still getting used to this tool....I know that didn't format well...I tried to link on both last name and first name, and yes, I think I know I have an issue with duplicate data. This is a clean up job for a client...I wanted to update on the records that did match, then I will insert what didn't.