# update mysql table multiple columns using another table

Tags: mysql

i have following tables 
(**Table: avg_month_val1**)

```
year                       
month        
evep                
sunshine_hrs             
rainfall     
max_temp               
min_temp
```

and

(**Table: reg_data3**)

```
id         
date                
time                  
rainfall                
evep                         
max_temp                   
min_temp    
sunshine_hrs
```

i wan to up date avg_month_val1 table using  reg_data3
i follow
[How do you update multiple fields from another table in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755024/how-do-you-update-multiple-fields-from-another-table-in-mysql)

here is my query

```
UPDATE `avg_month_val1` a,`reg_data3` b SET
a.`year`=YEAR(b.`date`),
a.`month`=MONTH(b.`date`),
a.`evep`=ROUND(AVG(b.evep),2),
a.`max_temp`=ROUND(AVG(b.max_temp),2), 
a.`min_temp`=ROUND(AVG(b.min_temp),2) ,
a.`rainfall`=ROUND(SUM(b.rainfall),2), 
a.`sunshine_hrs`=ROUND(AVG(b.sunshine_hrs),2)
WHERE a.`year`=YEAR(b.`date`)
```

but it gives following error

```
Error Code: 1111
Invalid use of group function
```

how i accomplish this

Comment: Could you explain more what are you trying to do ? The query is joining tables only by `year`. Suppose that the table `a` contains 12 records for a given year, which records should be updated ? It also would be helpfull if you provided an example of source data and expected results.

Comment: check two thing. first check all values are ok, I mean YEAR(b.date) has any value? and second check that data types are same in both tables? I mean can store values from b table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it this way

```
UPDATE avg_month_val1 t JOIN 
(
  SELECT YEAR(date) year,
         MONTH(date) month,
         ROUND(AVG(evep), 2) evep,
         ROUND(AVG(max_temp), 2) max_temp,
         ROUND(AVG(min_temp), 2) min_temp,
         ROUND(SUM(rainfall), 2) rainfall,
         ROUND(AVG(sunshine_hrs), 2) sunshine_hrs
    FROM reg_data3
   GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
) s 
    ON t.year = s.year
   AND t.month = s.month
   SET t.evep = s.evep,
       t.max_temp = s.max_temp, 
       t.min_temp = s.min_temp, 
       t.rainfall = s.rainfall, 
       t.sunshine_hrs = s.sunshine_hrs
```

Using `UPDATE` implies that you already have in table `avg_month_val1` rows with columns `year` and `month` populated and only want to update data columns (`evep`, ...) with aggregated values from `reg_data3`.

But if it's not the case and you want to `INSERT` all columns including `year` and `month` but be able to update existing rows with the same year and month values you can it using `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause

```
INSERT INTO avg_month_val1 (year, month, evep, max_temp, min_temp, rainfall, sunshine_hrs)
SELECT YEAR(date) year,
       MONTH(date) month,
       ROUND(AVG(evep), 2) evep,
       ROUND(AVG(max_temp), 2) max_temp,
       ROUND(AVG(min_temp), 2) min_temp,
       ROUND(SUM(rainfall), 2) rainfall,
       ROUND(AVG(sunshine_hrs), 2) sunshine_hrs
  FROM reg_data3
 GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       evep = VALUES(evep),
       max_temp = VALUES(max_temp), 
       min_temp = VALUES(min_temp), 
       rainfall = VALUES(rainfall), 
       sunshine_hrs = VALUES(sunshine_hrs)
```

**In order for this to work** you have to make sure that you have `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on (year, month) in `avg_month_val1`